# Common code base for developing an app for different smartphone OS's

Tags: android, ios, smartphone

I'm new to iOS/Android development so I would like to know what is the usual practice of developing an app for different platforms - is the whole code rewritten or the possibilities are used to choose some language, C or C++ for example, and keep most of the work in this language and then cover it with system specific stuff in corresponding language? I know about Android NDK and having C/C++ code in your iOS app, but the question is - is this usually used in practice - maybe later some other platforms might be added? The classical example would be the Angry Birds, of course, which I have even on my "smart" TV. Would be good to hear guys experienced in this area since I might be in the middle of making a decision. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try Qt framework as it's native to Symbian, officially ported to Android, and unofficially ported to iOS and Blackberry.  It's a C++ IDE at http://qt.nokia.com

Better yet, if you're into that kinda thing, try PhoneGap here: http://phonegap.com/  This will allow you to write your "app" code in HTML.... yes, HTML, and port it to just about anything.  Things that are normally OS-dependent are basically wrapped in PhoneGap's API including hardware: http://phonegap.com/about/feature/

Answer (score 1):

You should go check out the [Xamarin studio](http://xamarin.com/).  It allows you to write code in C# and reuse up to 80% of your code between the platforms.  They have some videos and tutorials for how to best write code that can be reused.

Answer (score 0):

THe classical example would be angry birds?  I've either hit a time warp to 20 years in the future, or you're thinking way too small.

But yes, it is quite common to write the majority of logic in C or C++ and just write system specific stuff and/or UI in the native language.

Comment: This makes perfect sense at this point in my project... I wish I considered writing the core of it in C

Comment: Don't write the core in C for this reason alone. You will spend more development and bug crunching time than you would if you just ported a managed code base like C# or Java

Comment: @rolls Not necessarily true.  I find myself spending more time thinking about and working around memory issues in garbage collected languages than I ever do in C++ or C, because the control levers just aren't there.

Comment: Why do you ever need to think about those things? They are rarely needed.

Comment: if you actual think its rarely needed, you either write nothing non trivial, or you write turds with horrible performance

Answer (score 0):

There are several cross-platform solutions on the market. Some of them use Java and C#, they usually are integrated with the common SDKs (such as Visual Studio, Eclipse). Some of them allow to easily develop and distribute web-apps using HTML5, Css3 and jQuery combination.

You can just surf for them on the net. I suppose it's not allowed to mention them here. If I'm wrong I will post the name of some of the most known solutions that I tried.